# Table with several TBODY tags in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I would like to create (in code) tree of controls that would render as a table with several TBODY tags, i.e.:

```
<TBODY>
    <TR>
        <TD></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD></TD>
    </TR>
</TBODY>
```

I tried both Table and HtmlTable controls but had no success. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you generating your data? You could use a templated control like a Repeater or ListView as that gives you full control of the HTML you're generating.

If you're wanting to create the controls purely in C# you can use the HtmlGenericControl (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx), you'll need to provide a tag type in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a class that implements IBindableTemplate, so all of the rendering has to be done in code. I will give the HtmlGenericControl a try. Thanks!